# change screen resolution with AppleScript

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, resolution

How can I change change screen resolution using AppleScript? If AppleScript can't do it, what about Terminal?

I tried with examples at [How to set screen resolution with a keyboard shortcut on Retina MBP?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59075/how-to-set-screen-resolution-with-a-keyboard-shortcut-on-retina-mbp), but they don't work anymore. I'm on MacBookPro Retina.

This is how the script definitively should start:

```
    tell application "System Preferences"
        activate
        reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.displays"
    end tell
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "System Preferences"
          -- insert magic
        end tell
    end tell
```

Now I just need to click on "Scaled" and select different display resolutions, but I don't know how these buttons are "called".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if still works on current versions of OS X, but somebody wrote a command line tool to get and set resolutions a few years ago: https://github.com/jhford/screenresolution

Comment: thank you! Although it still works, it doesn't work well. 1440x900 look completely different when set using Displays. Im guessing Retinas weren't around when this was created.

Comment: I wrote a similar lightweight command line tool (installable via Homebrew) that does support retina screens: https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer

Answer (score 5):

We have created a python script, called Display Manager that allows you programmatically set resolution, bit depth, underscan, mirroring, etc.

Give it a try and let us know if you want additional functionality

https://github.com/univ-of-utah-marriott-library-apple/display_manager

Comment: Worked for me! I created a Workflow using Automator and assigned a keyboard shortcut via System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts.

Comment: (My command for 1920x1080 @60 fps: `/path/to/display_manager.py res 1920 1080 60`)

Answer (score 2):

I was fiddling a round this for a while and I've found a simpler way to set the desired resolution. There is a tool [displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer/blob/master/README.md) that let's you save and restore the current display settings.

```
displayplacer "id:56A96CFC-7F21-168E-3D19-FC1626C9B248 res:2560x1440 hz:60 color_depth:8 scaling:on origin:(0,0) degree:0"
```

To get the current settings of your displays run `displayplacer list` it will output a `displayplacer` command that can be use to restore the current settings.
Here is how I'm setting my display to '2560x1440'

This gif shows nicely displayplacer features:

[image: logo]

Comment: Thank you for this tip! I used it here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/463243/53510

Answer (score 0):

I've included two scripts in this post for making the display resolution higher or lower.  Taking it one step further, I also included the process of assigning keyboard shortcuts.

[Changing display resolution with AppleScript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/263365/210407)